# how do I make sda1 or sdb1 bigger

Tags: ubuntu, mount, disk-usage, disk, cloud

I'm working with Google Cloud services. After I've cloned a VM, I type `lsblk` after ssh'ing into it and can see that the partition `sda1` is only 10 GB, which is only 10% of what I paid for.

I am not a Linux admin at all and I really don't know what this means. Why is the partition small?

1. How is this be fixed on-prem? I think it may have to do with using an external utility from another boot device
2. I don't expect anyone to help here, but how would I fix this on Google Cloud too? That would be great!

Here is the output of `sudo parted --list`:

```
Model: Google PersistentDisk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  107GB  107GB  primary  ext4         boot
Model: Google PersistentDisk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 268GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  10.7GB  10.7GB  primary  ext4         boot
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  **;-)** What's the output of `sudo parted --list`?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: It does appear to me that /dev/sda is 107GB, and /dev/sda 10.7GB?

Comment: yes I can see that too. Can you tell me exactly how I fix it?

Comment: The output of `parted --list` and your description of the output of `lsblk` do not match: It seems you have a 107GB bootable `/dev/sda` disk with a 107GB partition and a 268 GB bootable `/dev/sdb` disk with a 10.7 GB partition (probably `/dev/sdb1`).  If you can boot off the 107GB one, it should be trivial to resize the 10.7 GB one. Can you confirm my suspicions so I can give you a well-funded answer? (I don't use Google Cloud MaaS but Bare Metal Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you are expected to create a second partition of ~97GB, leaving `/` as a basic 10GB.

Alternatively you could chance deleting the current partition and recreating a full sized one immediately in its place. The essential requirement here would be to ensure the starting sector was the same for the new partition as is for the old. Follow this with something like `resize2fs` and then force `fsck` on next boot.

---

Looking more closely, it seems that indeed the partition is 107MB, but you say the filesystem is currently only 10MB:

```
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  107GB  107GB  primary  ext4         boot
```

If you really want to increase the size of the single filesystem to the full amount available, just run `resize2fs /dev/sda1` and it will be extended for you. (Note that this operation is not easily reversible.)

Comment: Thanks Im not sure how to fill in the gaps I hope someone else does!

Comment: @Mike additional information added for you